# Pass value from one form to another (no Infopath, no ContentType) - no save

Tags: infopath, form, newform

In Sharepoint 2013, I have two Lists. One list named "Turtle" and one list named "Improvements." On my list Turtle I have a single line of text. What I want is a button on the right hand side of the line of text and after you click this button the entered text passes to the list "Improvements" and there at the Title-Field so you can add a new Item to the other list without typing a title because you named it after your entered text.

The form should not need to be saved before creating the item in Improvements. I would prefer not to use InfoPath or Content Types. InfoPath would be used only as a last resort.

Comment: If you don't save, what happens with the Turtle-NewForm when you open the second? If Turtle isn't saved your Improvements won't have a "Parent" (you want a Parent-Child relationship)

Answer (score 1):

I would go about this using JQuery and SPServices. You can use JavaScript to insert a new button to the right of the field, or you could customize the form using SharePoint Designer and add a button there.

The SPServices [UpdateListItems](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=UpdateListItems) method allows you to create a new item in a different list. The users will need contribute permissions to the Improvements list for this to work. Here is a sample, where `newTitle` is the value typed into the single line of text. You can follow many examples on google for retrieving the text from that field.

```
$().SPServices({
        webURL: http://myserver/mysite,
        listName: Improvements,
        operation: "UpdateListItems",
        batchCmd: "New",
        valuepairs: [
            ["Title", newTitle],
        ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions Erin. I've managed to get the code working a little but i can't get it to work properly.

Now I have:

```
    <script language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#addbutton").click(function () {
            var title = $('nobr:contains("Title")').closest('td').next('td').text();
            AddListItem(title);
        });

    });

    function AddListItem(TitleField) {
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "UpdateListItems",
            async: false,
            batchCmd: "New",
            listName: "testcustomlist",
            valuepairs: [["Title", TitleField]],
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                alert("Element wurde erstellt.");
            }
        });
    }
</script> 
<div class="button"> 
   <input name="add" id="addbutton" type="button" value="add new element"/>&#160;</div>
```

I've posted the code on the EditForm (Standard) in a CEWP. For var title i want to get the text written on the single line of text - i know that i need to use nobr and contains. It returns No Title.